# Android studio not resloving attributes of sealed class in NavBarGraph

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to implement the bottom navbar. The nav graph is unable to find the **route** member of the sealed class. Here's the code of the sealed class:

```
   import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Home
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Person
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ShoppingCart
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector

sealed class BottomBarScreen(route:String,title:String,icon:ImageVector){
    object Home: BottomBarScreen(route="home",
        title = "Home",
        icon=Icons.Default.Home)
    object Dashboard: BottomBarScreen("dashboard","Dashboard",Icons.Filled.Menu)
    object Orders: BottomBarScreen("orders","Orders",Icons.Default.ShoppingCart)
    object Profile: BottomBarScreen("profile","Profile",Icons.Default.Person)
}
```

Android Studio does not detect route elements in the NavBarGraph. Here's the photo of that:
[image]

What's the reason for it?

Comment: I think you need to use data class instead of object then you should be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

In the primary constructor of sealed class BottomBarScreen write val before specifying the attributes.

```
 import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Home
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Person
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ShoppingCart
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector

sealed class BottomBarScreen(val route:String,val title:String,val icon:ImageVector){
    object Home: BottomBarScreen(route="home",
        title = "Home",
        icon=Icons.Default.Home)
    object Dashboard: BottomBarScreen("dashboard","Dashboard",Icons.Filled.Menu)
    object Orders: BottomBarScreen("orders","Orders",Icons.Default.ShoppingCart)
    object Profile: BottomBarScreen("profile","Profile",Icons.Default.Person)
}
```